# Background image in Custom Title

Tags: android, android-layout

I searched and couldn't find a solution that was unique to my problem. I need to replace the below background color with a background image. Your help is awesomely appreciated.

**Edit: Problem solved. I was trying to edit the wrong xml file.**

```
<resources>
    <style name='CustomTitleBackground'>
        <item name='android:background'>#3b5998</item>
    </style>
    <style name='CustomTheme' parent='android:Theme'>
        <item name='android:windowTitleSize'>45dip</item>
        <item name='android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle'>@style/CustomTitleBackground</item>
     </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do:

```
<style name='CustomTitleBackground'>
  <item name='android:background'>@drawable/my_background_image</item>
</style>
```

?